# paperclip duplicate url error

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, paperclip, alias

I'm attempting to upload an image via ajax using paperclip.

I'm using the qqfileuploader for the ajax stuff and it doesn't seem to have an option where I can define the parameter name for the post request.

The parameters sent from the ajax post are

```
qqfile=filename.jpg
```

so in my model, I have aliased qqfile to photo

```
  alias_attribute :qqfile, :photo
   has_attached_file :photo
   attr_accessible :title, :photo
```

when I upload a file via ajax, I get the following errors

```
 Parameters: {"qqfile"=>"Penguins.jpg"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method User.page.
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method RoleUser.page.
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method Role.page.
  Role Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `role_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `role_users`.`role_id` WHERE `role_users`.`user_id` = 1
  SQL (0.7ms)  BEGIN
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method Task.page.
[paperclip] Duplicate URL for photo with /system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename. This will clash with attachment defined in Recipe class
```

I'm not sure if the CSRF token will be an issue, there is a token on the page, so maybe I just need to be sending that, I assume I can get it is a variable with javascript?

But what is the deal with the duplicate url??? Am I not aliasing correctly? Can I not alias a paperclip object for some reason?

my controller is also very simple

```
def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
    @recipe.author_id=current_user.id
    if @recipe.save
        return render :json => @recipe
    else
        return render :text => 'an error occured saving the recipe'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you provide (all) the exact calls of `has_attached_file`?

Comment: @mosch, I added the has_attached_file and attr_accessible, it's just the basics as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails generates a security token for POST events based on the user's session. If that token is missing or doesn't match what's expected, the session will be reset. See this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures

As for the duplicate URL, are you sure your URL pattern is specific enough? It looks to me that if you upload a file with the same name for the same model instance you'd have a problem. It would help to see your controller code.

Comment: thanks @yock, i've beenw working on the csrf issue for the last bit, and just saw your comment, so I do need to pass that attribute somehow, but haven't quite got that working yet. This process should work http://eunikorn.blogspot.com/2011/07/working-with-backbonejs-in-harmony-with.html, but isn't so far. 

I've included my controller code, which is really basic, so also shouldn't be the source of the problem, but maybe.